# Icons are missing from Visual Editor

Tags: wp-admin, block-editor, visual-editor, bug, icon

## The Problem

I've been grappling with this bug over several days now to no luck. When editing either a post or a page, all icons in the Visual Editor are missing:

[image]

As you can see this, includes the icon for the Gutenberg Add Block, which is completely invisible and here highlighted by its alt text. Also notice that the icons in the WP Admin section/toolbar display as normal, indicating the problem is only with the icons of the Visual Editor.

[image]

## What I've Tried

To date, my extensive Googling, tweaking and testing has proved useless. The following is a list of all the solutions I've tried so far, from the standard to the slightly more complex:

- Clearing browser cache/viewing the page in private browsing mode ([as suggested here](https://www.newtonbaba.com/white-text-and-missing-buttons-in-wordpress-visual-editor))
- Deactivating all plugins ([as suggested here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-missing-icons-problems-with-html-editing/#post-10183491))
- Checking that the values of *Wordpress Address* and *Site Address* in `Settings > General` match
- Going to `Settings > Permalinks` and clicking Save Changes ([as suggested here](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/my-website-is-in-a-redirect-loop/))
- Adding `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );` to wp-config
- Adding `define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );` to wp-config
- Adding `define(‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false);` to wp-config ([as suggested here](https://www.newtonbaba.com/white-text-and-missing-buttons-in-wordpress-visual-editor))
- Adding `$_SERVER[“HTTPS”] = “on”;` to wp-config ([as suggested here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/after-adding-ssl-wordpress-content-doesnt-work-properly/#post-9981709))
- Replacing the `wp-includes/js/TinyMCE` folder entirely with the same folder from a fresh Wordpress download ([as suggested here](https://www.newtonbaba.com/white-text-and-missing-buttons-in-wordpress-visual-editor))
- Replacing the entirety of `wp-admin` with the same folder from a fresh Wordpress download ([as suggested here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-missing-icons-problems-with-html-editing/#post-10184173))
- Using `wp-cli` to do a site-wide search-and-replace of `http://www.myexamplesite.com` to `https://www.myexamplesite.com` ([as suggested here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/some-of-the-icons-are-missing-from-the-dashboard/#post-9566882))
- Disabling both HTTPS Enforce and and External Links Rewrite in using Siteground's cPanel (but *not* deleting the SSL certificate itself)

Not a single one of the above solutions results in the icons being restored again, even when I check the changes using Incognito/Private Browsing to counteract caching.

## Possible Cause

I have *some* suspicion that this issue could have been caused by activating free Let's Encrypt SSL on the server, due to [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-editor-missing-icons-problems-with-html-editing/#post-10195927), and I also don't recall this issue occurring before I made that change, but I'm unsure as to a) how exactly enabling the free Let's Encrypt SSL would cause such an issue, and b) how it would be fixed.

Has anyone else dealt with this before?

Comment: Maybe it's a "mixed content" issue.. But have you tried disabling the SSL certificate? And the `+` ("add block" icon) is actually an inline `svg` element.. so right-click on the button and inspect the source - what do you see? And have you tried or are you using [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/)?

Comment: @SallyCJ The SSL cert is handled via the hosting server's cPanel (Siteground), I try to keep plugin use very minimal, especially where it can be accomplished in some other way. I completely forgot to include it in the above list but I also tried disabling both Force SSL itself and the option to rewrited links (which is for preventing mixed content), but none of that made any difference. The only thing I haven't done is delete the SSL certificate to well and truly disable SSL, but such a drastic step can't be necessary surely?

Comment: @SallyCJ As for the Add Block SVG, neither it nor the containers around it are showing as hidden in the markup, and the CSS appears normal, nothing there seems to be preventing it from displaying.

Comment: I would just try to completely remove the certificate and disable SSL, then check if that fixes the issue with the icons. If not, then at least it confirmed the cause is not SSL (or the certificate). But if yes, then try reinstalling the certificate and enable SSL. And if the issue persists, then I guess it's time to get help from SiteGround..

Comment: But have you tried switching to Twenty Nineteen or any of the default themes?

Comment: @SallyCJ I've posted an update as an answer.

Comment: I have the same issue (https://aixpatria.com - Siteground site). Unfortunately above work-around does not seem to work for me. Did all that is descrived but still cannot see the icons in the visual editor. opened a ticket.

Comment: Contracting Siteground actually immediately helped with this solution: Hello Nicolaas,

Thank you for contacting us.

I've noticed that you are using Cloudflare on your website which is enabled from your Site Tools.

I've cleared the Cloudflare cache and enabled "Development Mode".

Please clear your browser's cache and test the website on your end and get back to us with the results.

In case the issue persists, please provide us with WP Admin credentials (URL, username and password) so we can investigate further.

Best Regards,

Denis Draganov
Technical Support Team

Comment: @NicolaasPereboom Seems like a different issue. I wasn't using Cloudflare on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more days of frustrating testing, I managed to track the issue down to the External Links Rewrite option in Siteground's Site Tools, under SSL options. When HTTP Enforce is enabled with the optional External Links Rewrite option (being able to see these changes virtually immediately in the browser requires a [Force Refresh](https://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/), which was what has made testing this stuff so hard) the icons in Visual Editor go missing. When External Links Rewrite is turned off, the icons show up again.

I've contacted Siteground's customer support for a solution, but so far they claim they've been unable to reproduce the issue, despite the fact I've so far managed to reproduce it on both of the two systems I have access to: Firefox and Chrome running on Windows 7, and Firefox running on MacOS High Sierra.

#### UPDATE:

Within 6 hours of filing the ticket, Siteground support finally escalated it to a more senior technical person, who then gave me the following response:

[image]

This response confirms what I'd suspected: that the "External Links Rewrite" option in Siteground's control panel (which they call Site Tools) is broken. They also claim that the team were already aware of the issue, although I'm skeptical of this given that it took a few responses for the initial support to escalate the ticket and the fact that the new React-based (and admittedly very good) Site Tools interface seems to have been [launched just a few weeks ago](https://www.siteground.com/blog/new-client-area-and-site-tools/).

In any case, Siteground insist a fix is on the way, and that in the meantime the solution is to disable HTTPS enforcement from the Site Tools panel entirely, and instead download its SG Optimiser plugin, enabling *HTTPS Enforce* and *External Links Rewrite* from there. I've tested this solution and can confirm that it solves the issue.

I inspected my `.htaccess` file after enabling these options with SG Optimiser, and it seemed to me that the only thing it was adding was the following Apache directive:

```
# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
```

As someone who tries his best to run a bare-minimum installation with only the most necessary plugins, writing code for everything else, I wondered if this was the only thing SG Optimiser was doing to force HTTPS, and if I could replace it by simply adding the same directives to .htaccess myself.

However, on further inquiry from Siteground support, this doesn't seem to be the case:

[image]

Now, the only thing left to do is to wait for Siteground to fix this bug in the new Site Tools interface, after which I'll finally be able to remove the unnecessary SG Optimiser plugin and enforce HTTPS from the control panel itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this issue myself on a new siteground install.

After some troubleshooting I found disabling all the Frontend Optimization options in the SG Optimizer plugin brought the editor icons back after purging the cache.

Then I enabled them one by one (except Combine CSS Files this has caused issues in the past and wasn't enabled before anyway)

I purged the cache after re-enabling each option checking the icons were still showing on the editor page after a page refresh.

It seems to have done the job.

Pete

Comment: I've never installed SG Optimizer on my site, although I suspect the issues are related. Looking into SG Optimiser, it seems that one of its most touted functions is to enable the External Links Rewrite option for SSL from within Wordpress without needing to log into the Siteground panel, so this seems to corroborate my finding that that particular feature is responsible for this.